# Installing Multiple Vesions of GStreamer

Tags: ubuntu, gstreamer, ubuntu-10.04

Is it Possible to Install GStreamer Packages (eg: gstreamer-0.10.31, gst-plugins-base-0.10.31, gst-plugins-good-0.10.23) in non **standard location** (Generally we will install in /usr/local) ?

Because we want to test applications in **different versions of GStreamer**. So is it possible to install different versions in a single machine to non standard paths as following **(as against to default /usr/local)**:

- /home/gst-10.0
- /home/gst-zx.x
- /home/gst-xy.y

When I tried Installing in non standard location, it was prompted with dependent packages as they weren't exist in that location (By default they exist in /usr/local) as follows:

i did set LD_LIBRARY_PATH, PKG_CONFIG_PATH and PATH Variables

Suppose for example if I am installing in /home/gst-10.0 location

I have the following values set for the above variables **(I am working on Ubuntu 10.04LTS)**

**LD_LIBRARY_PATH** = /home/gst-10.0/lib:/home/gst-10.0/lib/gstreamer-0.10:/usr/lib 
**PKG_CONFIG_PATH** = /home/gst-10.0/lib/pkgconfig 
**PATH** = /home/gst-10.0/bin:$PATH and 
I used the **prefix** as **/home/gst-10.0** while doing "./configure"

For installing the GStreamer(10.04) packages, i have the following dependencies (these are all promted for installation while I was trying to install each Gstreamer packages):

- liboil
- zlib
- gettext
- glib
- libxml
- libIDL
- ORBit2
- intltool
- atk
- pango
- freetype
- fontconfig
- cairo
- dbus
- gconf
- gtk

In which dbus,gconf,gtk packages failing to install with some compilation errors in this nonstandard location, but working in default /usr/local location. So by this way i am unable to proceed further.

Looking for your thoughts on this.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's completely possible.  I've done it a lot.  I even run different versions uninstalled.

A lot of existing buildscripts are already out there; jhbuild is one example.

Why would you want to recompile dependencies like dbus, gconf, and so on ? What's the point ? You only need to compile gstreamer and friends with the prefix you want.  They'll happily use your system installed packages for dependencies.

You should not have /home/gst-10.0/lib/gstreamer-0.10 on your LD_LIBRARY_PATH; plugins are picked up automatically by GStreamer in the plugin directory.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, so is it the $PATH, $PKG_CONFIG_PATH variables be same as above ?

Comment: yes, looks fine to me.  Check gstreamer/scripts/gst-uninstalled for further hints.